# Get location distance and speed android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, distance

Hi I am trying to fetch location in every 5 seconds and calculate the speed and total distance or the trip but it is not giving exact distance and speed, below is my code please help. TIA

```
public class LocationUpdater extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

private double latitude ;
private double longitude ;
Session session;
Context context;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;

public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL =
        MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 10;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL =
        MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;

private static final int DESIRED_ACCURACY = 10;
private static final float SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 10f;

/**
 * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
 */
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

public LocationUpdater() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    context = LocationUpdater.this;
    session = Session.getSession(context);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    return START_STICKY;
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    try{


        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);

        requestLocationUpdate();

    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(session.getTrip_status().equalsIgnoreCase(Utils.trip_status_started))
        startService(new Intent(LocationUpdater.this,LocationUpdater.class));
}
```

I am able to get results but updates and not accurate and not smooth at all. Please let me know if it is the correct way of doing it or I should try something else.

Below is my location updater code

```
 private void fetchMyLocation(){
    try{
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();

                    Log.wtf("ankit","accuracy "+location.getAccuracy());

                    if (location.hasAccuracy()  && location.getAccuracy() <= DESIRED_ACCURACY) {
                        // This is your most accurate location.
                        Log.wtf("ankit","latitude:::"+latitude);
                        Log.wtf("ankit","longitude:::"+longitude);

                        session.setCurrentLatitude(""+latitude);
                        session.setCurrentLongitude(""+longitude);

                        if(session.getTrip_status().equalsIgnoreCase(Utils.trip_status_started)){
                            updateDistanceAndSpeed(latitude,longitude);
                        } else {
                            UpdateLocationListner.getInstance().changeState(latitude,longitude,"");
                        }
                    }

                }


            }
        });
    }catch (SecurityException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and this is how i calculate speed and distance

```
    // update speed and distance

private void updateDistanceAndSpeed(double latitude,double longitude){

    long currentTimeMills = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (session.getLastLatitude().equalsIgnoreCase("")
                && session.getLastLongitude().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            session.setLastLatitude(""+latitude);
            session.setLastLongitude(""+longitude);
        }else {
            synchronized (this){
                try{
                    String lat = ""+latitude;
                    String lng = ""+longitude;
                    double speed = 0;

                    if(!lat.equalsIgnoreCase(session.getLastLatitude())
                            && !lng.equalsIgnoreCase(session.getLastLongitude())){

                        Location locationA = new Location("point A");

                        locationA.setLatitude(latitude);
                        locationA.setLongitude(longitude);

                        Location locationB = new Location("point B");

                        locationB.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(session.getLastLatitude()));
                        locationB.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(session.getLastLongitude()));

                        if(session.getDistance().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                            session.setDistance("0");

                        Log.wtf("ankit","total distance:"+session.getDistance());

                        float lastDistance = Float.parseFloat(session.getDistance());

                        float distance[] = new float[1];

                        Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude,
                                Double.parseDouble(session.getLastLatitude()),
                                Double.parseDouble(session.getLastLongitude()), distance);



                        if(!session.getLastTimeStamp().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                            long lastTime = Long.parseLong(session.getLastTimeStamp());
                            long timeDifference = currentTimeMills - lastTime;

                            long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeDifference);
                            speed = distance[0]/diffInSec;
                        } else {
                            speed = 0;
                        }

                        speed = speed*3.6;
                        speed = Utils.round(speed,2);

                        float roundDistance = Utils.round(distance[0],2);
                        Log.wtf("ankit","roundDistance"+roundDistance);
                        float final_distance = lastDistance+roundDistance;
                        UpdateLocationListner.getInstance().changeState(latitude,longitude,""+speed+"/"+final_distance);
                        session.setDistance(""+final_distance);


                    } else {
                        UpdateLocationListner.getInstance().changeState(latitude,longitude,"0/0");
                    }
                    // send speed


                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            session.setLastLatitude(""+latitude);
            session.setLastLongitude(""+longitude);
            session.setLastTimeStamp(""+currentTimeMills);
        }



}
```

Comment: To get location fix on GPS device, usually it takes way longer than 5 seconds (around 30 seconds at least depending on many factors) so I think there is no point  trying to request location fix every 5 seconds.

Comment: you shouldn't post your entire code and ask to correct. it. Localize the problem, use debug, print results into the log, etc.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara ok I will convert to 30 seconds and then I will test and edit my question thanks

Comment: @VladMatvienko I respect your opinion but I am not able to find the exact problem so I posted it anyways thanks

Comment: `I am not able to find the exact problem` have you tried? how exactly?

Comment: @VladMatvienko i have edited my question and I have tried on different mobiles and did real time testing in customers vehicle. Basically I want to calculate the route , total distance and real time speed between start trip and stop trip of a vehicle in my app.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass latitudes and longitude

```
public void setLatLng(LatLng origins, LatLng destinations) {
        url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?" +
                "origins=" + origins.latitude + "," + origins.longitude + "" +
                "&destinations=" + destinations.latitude + "," + destinations.longitude + "" +
                "&mode=driving" +
                "&language=en-EN" +
                "&sensor=false";
    }
```

Handle the response of this URL here give the distance and time between two latitudes and longitude so now you need to calculate speed and for the speed you use

speed = distance / time

Comment: I do not want to call any api as it will consume internet but anyway thanks